# Finding MATLAB Linter on Ubuntu

Tags: matlab

After taking ages to install matlab on Ubuntu, I am struggling with finding the path for the linter (which is supposed to be called mlint) for MATLAB.
My path is /usr/local/MATLAB/R2021b and inside it, there is for example the /bin/ folder. But in none of the subfolders I can find that. The aim is to use MATLAB on VSCode instead of the terrible standard programme.

Does anybody know how to find that linter?

I found some manuals for Windows, but they do not help at all.

Comment: There are already extensions, which try that. Matlab supports it by the matlab engine. And without it it will be nearly impossible due to MEX, toolboxes and other functionalities. For small simple files it seems to be possible to cross compile, see here: https://www.pythonpool.com/convert-matlab-to-python/ and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=matlab&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick find showed the following files, '.' in my case being the 'R2020b' folder.

```
./bin/glnxa64/mlint
./bin/glnxa64/libnativemlint.so
./bin/glnxa64/mlint.sh
./bin/glnxa64/builtins/matlab_toolbox_general_builtins/mwmlintrospect_builtinimpl.so
./bin/glnxa64/libmwmlint.so
./bin/glnxa64/libmwmlintrospect.so
```

Comment: This is correct. Thank you. Why didn't the locate command find that on my computer? Is there a way to use that in a wrong way?